# Drop down box text disappears after completing a function, how can I get it to display what option was chosen?

Tags: javascript, html

The functions below work fine, the only thing I need help with is that when I pick an option from a drop down menu, it runs the function, but it erases all of the options in the drop down box. How can I get it NOT to do that and continue displaying my original options in the same drop down box?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function gbid(s)    {
return document.getElementById(s);
}

function myCount()  {
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("somefilepathhere.xlsx");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");

var agent,count
agent=document.getElementById("tAgent").value;

    if  (agent=="Agent1")
        {
        count=gbid('tAgent').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(1,1).Value;
}
        else if (agent=="Agent2")
        {
        count=gbid('tAgent').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(2,1).Value;
}
document.getElementById("disphere").innerHTML = count;


excel.Quit();
excel.Application.Quit();

}

function saveToExcel() {
var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
myApp.visible = false;
var xlCellTypeLastCell = 11;
var x = document.forms["f1"]["tAgent"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("You must select an 'Entered By' option!");
    return false;
}
    else

var myWorkbook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
var myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1);


myWorksheet.Activate;
objRange = myWorksheet.UsedRange;
objRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate;
newRow = myApp.ActiveCell.Row + 1;

    alert('A new log was created on row '+newRow);

strNewCell = "A" + newRow;

myApp.Range(strNewCell).Activate;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,1).value = f1.tMemberid.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,2).value = f1.tDate.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,3).value = f1.tRep.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,4).value = f1.tIssuerep.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,5).value = f1.tLOB.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,6).value = f1.tContactnum.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,7).value = f1.tMembername.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,8).value = f1.tIssid.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,9).value = f1.tTypeofissue.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,10).value = f1.tDiscofissue.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,11).value = f1.tTimesent.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,12).value = f1.tSendto.value;
myWorksheet.Cells(newRow,13).value = f1.tAgent.value;

myWorkbook.Close(true);
myApp.Workbooks.Close;
myApp.Close;
alert('Process Complete!');
}
</script>

<table >
<tr>
    <td class="tb_bor" Align="center" ><h1>ACA Issues Tracker</h1><br />

    <b>Entered By: </b>
    <select name="tAgent" id="tAgent" style="80% !important;" onchange="myCount()">
    <option value="" ></option>
    <option value="Agent1" >Agent 1</option>
    <option value="Agent2" >Agent 2</option>
    </select>
    <br />You have completed: <p id="disphere"></p>
<hr>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below line you overwrite the inner text of your select field:

```
count = gbid( 'tAgent' ).innerText = excel_sheet.Cells( 1,1 ).Value;
                                   ^
                                   |
```

Allthough I'm not clear on what you desire to achieve with the code because I don't understand your usecase, I think you might have mistaken the second equals sign with a string concatenation or something?

This might be what you tried to achieve:

```
count = gbid( 'tAgent' ).innerText + ' ' + excel_sheet.Cells( 1,1 ).Value;
```

---

This is a corrected version of your function:

```
function myCount()  {
    var excel = new ActiveXObject( 'Excel.Application' ),
        excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open( 'somefilepathhere.xlsx' ),
        excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets( 'Sheet1' ),
        agent = document.getElementById( 'tAgent' ).value,
        count;

    if  ( agent === 'Agent1' ) {
        count = excel_sheet.Cells( 1,1 ).Value;
    } else if ( agent === 'Agent2' ) {
        count = excel_sheet.Cells( 2,1 ).Value;
    }
    document.getElementById( 'disphere' ).innerHTML = count;

    excel.Quit();
    excel.Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I made the adjustments. Even though it now displays the options in the drop down box, it also displays the drop down content in the results section <p id="disphere"> </p>. Almost there, I just don't get why its doing that. And I'm sorry if I'm not making sense at the moment, been up for 37.5 hours now...

Comment: It does that because you prepend the dropdown content to the excel value with ```gbid( 'tAgent' ).innerText + ' ' + ```. You may simply want to get rid of that piece and you'd be fine. However I can only guess why it has been there in the first place ;p
Better get some sleep now!

Comment: I was actually trying to pull the info from an excel sheet. I've erased it but now it states the resuts are undefined. I will trouble shoot from here if you have no other suggestions and I think you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I updated my answer with a fixed version of your original function. You might want to ```console.log``` the values of ```count``` you recieve for the different select options. Check if excel returns anything at all. The function should work just right from here.
Good luck on finding the error! :)

Comment: You were right! Completely right! I didn't see an additional character I left behind when I deleted it like you said, took it out and bam! its going 100%! Thank you so much for your help! I think I've done enough for.... damn its Monday already... I'm going to bed! Thanks again! If I could score you up a point, I would! Thanks again!

Comment: Ha, congrats! Glad to have helped you, now sleep tight! :)